# Retrieve build info of a SNAPSHOT jar from artifactory using gradle

Tags: github, jenkins, gradle, artifactory

Before going forward, I realize this question is too broad. But I couldn't figure out the proper verbiage to search either here in `SO` or on `GOOGLE`.

If this question is a duplicate, then please excuse me in advance and provide me the link to the original question.

**Problem :**

We are working on creating testing framework. One of the requirements is to publish a report at the end of the testing phase with build information. We need to provide information like who committed the latest change we are testing, what is the build version we are using for testing etc.

In our current setup, We are using github as `SCM`. Whenever there is a commit to the SCM, a build is triggered on Jenkins and if the build is successful, the jar is deployed to JFrog Artifactory. I am trying to come up with a gradle script to get the necessary information.

Any pointers to the following questions are highly appreciated:

1. Which plugin can I use to retrieve the info for a SNAPSHOT jar from Artifactory?
2. Which plugin can I use to retrieve Jenkins build info using the build number retrieved from Q1?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is what you were asking for, but have you looked into the [Artifactory Build Info](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Build+Integration) file?

The [Artifactory Jenkins Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Artifactory+Plugin#ArtifactoryPlugin-ConfiguringGradleBuilds) can collect build information for you and publish that information to the Artifactory server (If you choose to "collect and publish build info").

The build information can then be viewed on the artifactory server and also fetched using a simple [REST call](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-BuildInfo).

HTH,

Or